# How to add glue to \baselineskip in preamble?

Tags: line-spacing

I can alter the leading with `\linespread` in preamble, but it won't add glue.

Any straightforward specification like `\baselinekip=<length> plus <glue>` works only inside `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. What is the correct way to place such alterations in the preamble?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to add glue to the baseline skip. That would be an area where I'd really not want any stretch or shrink)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At `\begin{document}` latex issues `\normalsize` which sets the initial font size and baseline skip. this command must be defined in the class (or if you must, redefined in the preamble)

For example the standard class 10pt option sets

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
```

So the default is a 10pt font on a 12pt baseline.

This could be redefined but (to put it mildly) it would be highly unusual to have flexible glue as a baseline spacing.